# how to overwrite, or delete the file, used by writefile() calls?

Tags: maxima

I use the following to save screen output to a file

```
writefile("file.txt"),
tex(expression),
closefile()
```

The above sends the output of the tex() to the file automatically. which is all and well and what I want. (side-point: It also sends an annoying NIL  line each time to the file, which I had to parse put later).

Now, when running the above code again, the file is appended to, which is not what I want. I want to either overwrite the file each time, or if there is a way to delete the file, so I can call delete on it before.

I looked at help and not able to find a command to delete a file, and I also see no option to tell writefile() to overwrite the file?

Is there an option or way around this? I am on windows 7, Maxima version: 5.36.1
Lisp: SBCL 1.2.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are trying to capture the output of `tex` into a file. If so, here are a couple of other ways to do it:

```
tex (expr, destination);
```

where `destination` is either a file name (which is appended) or a stream, as created by `opena` or `openw` and closed by `close`. By the way, `destination` could be `false`, in which case `tex` returns a string.

```
with_stdout (destination, tex (expr));
```

where again `destination` is either a file name (which is appended or clobbered, as determined by the global flag `file_output_append`) or a stream.

`with_stdout` could be useful if you want to mix in some output not generated by `tex`, e.g., `print("% some commentary");`.